# Customize ToolBar for iPhone App

Tags: ios, iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

i want to change the images of my UIBarButtonItems but without a tint and without resizing it.
It went just fine with my buttons in the navigationBar.

This is my approach:

```
    UIButton *mySettingsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *settingsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-greyscale.png"];
    mySettingsButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, settingsImage.size.width, settingsImage.size.height);
    [mySettingsButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [mySettingsButton setImage:settingsImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mySettingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(performSettingsSegue)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *mySettingsBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:mySettingsButton];
    UIBarButtonItem *settingsBarButton = (UIBarButtonItem *)[self.view viewWithTag:1000];
    settingsBarButton = mySettingsBarButton;
```

I don't know what to do. It is even possible the remove the tint of a BarButtonItem within the toolbox? I just want my image without any changes. 
What should i do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your UIButton initialisation code, try this:

```
UIButton *mySettingsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *settingsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-greyscale.png"];
mySettingsButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, sttingsImage.size.width, settingsImage.size.height);
/* then your code */
```

Comment: I changed my post to your solution. Do mean it like that? It doesn't work though..